# Using LIKE in a join statement

Tags: sql, string, where-clause, sql-like

I need to form a select statement to filter the table from my artists table with all the artists that start with the letter 'Q' and their respective songs.

Artist table columns: artist_id, name.
Song table columns: song_id, title, minutes, seconds, genre_id.
song_artist columns(junction): song_id, artist_id;

Comment: Please show us sample data for both tables and the corresponding expected result.

Comment: You will use `LIKE` in `WHERE` clause after `JOOIN`.

Comment: Please tag the database engine that you are using , e.g. SQL Server or MySQL. The sql tag is only for the language which they all use.

Comment: @DeanOC - Why do you believe that MySQL and SQL Server solutions would be any different?

Comment: updated info in about question

Comment: @PM77-1 The sql tag info says "Questions should include ... a tag for the DBMS implementation (e.g. MySQL, PostgreSQL, Oracle, MS SQL Server, IBM DB2, etc.)...". I was merely giving examples of two DBMS commonly used by new contributors.

Answer (score 1):

Consider:

```
select a.*, s.*
from artist a
inner join song_artist sa on sa.artist_id = a.artist_id
inner join song s on s.song_id = sa.song_id
where a.name like 'Q%'
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

```
select * from Artists t1
left outer join Song_Artist t2 on t1.Artist_ID=t2.ArtistID
left outer join Songs t3 on t2.SongID=t3.Song_Id
where t1.ArtistName like 'Q%'
```

Comment: This one covers all bases, by allowing for the situation where a matching artist has no songs.

Answer (score 0):

Pretty basic.

`...where artists like 'Q%'...`